# Method to stop an Await from executing if there's an empty Object from Promise but shouldn't return an error and execute other tasks

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

So what I want to achieve is that when a function returns an empty Object from the Promise, the Await function must not be executed and the rest of the Application must carry on executing other tasks. As the object that is returned maybe not always be available but should be returned when available.

```
    function getData(Data) : Promise<Object> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        request({
           // Method 
        }, (err, resp, file)=> {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve({
                   // Return object infomation
                });
            }
        });
    });
}

let someData = await Promise.all(data.map(getData)); 
// This should have a part that ignores if getData is empty and this await function ignored.
```

The rest of the application should be able to run as normal. I have tried to use:

```
.catch(error => {  });
```

But didn't work the way I wanted it to work

Comment: Your code looks like it does what you want it to, but if there is an error then there is no `try{}catch(e){}` for your `await Promise.all(...)` which might prevent your application from carrying on, depending on the rest of your code.

Comment: Are you saying that if `resolve( )` returns an empty object, you want to `throw` an error and not finish executing the rest of the `Promise.all` ?  If Yes, then add a `.then` block after the end of the `new Promise` check for empty and `throw` if it is, otherwise return the value.

Comment: I don't want it to throw an error, as it returning a empty object for the getData wouldn't be an error. As what is returned(resolved part) can be empty on some cases. Currently I get a `TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined` as the await function tries to execute the empty object. I want the await function to be jumped/ignored if the object is empty for getData.

Comment: @MotsaneM that error sounds like `data` is undefined. This has nothing to do with `getData` or `await`

Comment: @Bergi If you check my answer, I assigned an empty array to `data`. Previously, I actually wanted the whole line of the `await` function to be ignored. Data was undefined because the data for it won't always be available, making it undefined, which caused it to throw an error when trying to map the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be a better way, but what solved my issue was to pass an empty array to the data

```
if (isNullOrUndefined(data)) {
    data = [];
}
```

In this way the await function now works the way I want it to work and does not throw error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined